# java regex to extract 'only' the single digit numbers from a string

Tags: java, regex

let's say I have a string.

```
String str = "Hello6 9World 2, Nic8e D7ay!";

Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
```

the line above would give me 6, 9, 2, 8 and 7, which is perfect!

But if my string changes to..

```
String str = "Hello69World 2, Nic8e D7ay!";
```

note that the space between 6 and 9 is removed in this string.

and if I run..

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
```

it would give me 69, 2, 8 and 7.

my requirement is to extract the single digit numbers only. here, what I need is 2, 8, 7 and omit 69.

could you please help me to improve my regex? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each digit, you have to check if *it is not followed or preceded by a 
 digit*

You can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello69World 2, Nic8e D7ay!";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d(?!\\d)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

    System.out.println("***********");

    str = "Hello6 9World 2, Nic8e D7ay!";
    m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
2
8
7
***********
6
9
2
8
7
```